# Is there only one way to prove the Riemann Mapping Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

After looking through several complex analysis books and online resources (e.g. see [here](http://www.reed.edu/~jerry/311/rmt.pdf), [here](http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~richardt/414/414-ch7.pdf), and [here](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/tillmann/2007-complex/ComAna-Lectures.pdf)), it seems that there is basically one well-known proof of the Riemann Mapping Theorem, which goes through an argument involving a certain extremal problem in a normal family of holomorphic bijections.

Is this the only proof known to the mathematical community, or is there some other reason that (apparently) everyone chooses to teach the theorem this way?

Comment: One can prove the uniformization theorem and then the Riemann mapping theorem is a corollary.

Comment: @JohnMa I hadn't heard of the uniformization theorem before, but that does work! Do you know a reference for an accessible proof? It seems like a very difficult result.

Comment: Actually the proof of uniformization is just a little bit harder than the Riemann mapping theorem, you need to introduce the notion of Riemann surface and do some (somple) harmonic analysis. A proof can be found in "Riemann surface" by Farkas and Ika, GTM71